# Android Kotlin: Local Variables unavailable during debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-debug, android-studio-4.0

Starting today I am unable to debug locally scoped variables in Kotlin using Android Studio 4.0.1 (Build number AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763). Yesterday I did not have this issue.

I'm using android gradle 4.0.1 and build gradle of 6.1.1, after having tried rolling back I've reset to those.

Example code that I cannot debug:

```
private fun collapse(){
    val start = endIndicies[2]
    val end = endIndicies[3]
    ...
}
```

My debugger has no problem with resolving object scoped members, however locally scoped variables do not resolve when stepping through the code:

[image: My debugger has no problem with resolving object scoped members. start, end both list "cannot find local variable 'X' with type int" while endIndicies[2] = 19]

I'm running a debuggable build.

I have invalidated caches and restarted.

I have cleaned and rebuilt the project.

I have tried rolling back to previous gradle versions.

I have tried adding -dontobfuscate to my proguard file.

I've deleted my build files from the app folders, then rebuilt.

My debug config in the app/build.gradle file looks like this:

```
 debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
```

When I attempt to debug code in a library that is pulled in via gradle I have no issues debugging locally scoped variables.

```
app/build.gradle
dependencies{
    implementation project(':com.example.core')
    ...
}
```

So I'm fairly certain it's a configuration issue with the app module, and I suspect it's some rogue R8 obfuscation issue, though I'm not sure what.

Comment: Have you found a solution this?

Comment: No. I haven't noticed it recently but I think that's mostly because I've not been working in those imported libraries.